# How to deal with multiple lines input with Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Input i have to deal with:

```
2
2 3
3 3
```

My code:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int size = scanner.nextInt();

int[][] array = new int[size][2];
Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<2; j++) {
        array[i][j] = scanner2.nextInt();
    }
}
```

`2` is number of pairs that input contains. I want to put those pairs in 2D array but I need to get `2` first to declare size of an array. Above code works well in NetBeans where I give input like:

```
number 
enter 
pair 
enter
...
```

But all numbers come together in a format I posted above.

Any help?

Comment: you don't need scanner2, use only scanner

Comment: have you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods?

Comment: use `scr.next()` or `if(scr.hasNextInt()) x = scr.nextInt();`

Comment: Thank you. Don't know why i thought I had to create scanner after initializing array to make it work. And thanks for the link, lots of useful stuff, somehow I missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\n");
    System.out.println("Enter an integer");
    int size = scanner.nextInt();

    int[][] array = new int[size][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        String myInt = scanner.next();
        String[] myInts = myInt.split(" ");
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            array[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(myInts[j]);
        }
    }
    // print contents
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            System.out.println("[" + i + "]" + "[" + j + "] = " +array[i][j]);
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you